# onclick event does not work in an embedded html

Tags: javascript, html

I have loaded a html file text into a div element using `XMLHttpRequest`. What I am exactly trying to say is that I have a main html page which is filled with another html file.
The problem is that the onclick events of the embedded html's tags do not work. It seems that although I have added my script into embedded html, the functions cannot be found and called! Therefore, the below error can be seen in console.

> the function is not defined at 
>   HTMLParagraphElement.onclick

I checked the src of the attached script (in embedded html) and it was ok. I also tried to move my scripts to the main page, because I thought that embedded html would see the script of its parent html, though it didn't work out. I am sure that I did the same thing, but I cannot remember how exactly I did it in the past.

***The embedded Html***

```
<head>
    <title>Menue</title>
    <link href="../styles/menue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../scripts/menue.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="menueContainer">
    <h2 id="menueGameTitle">Monsters' Den</h2>
    <h4 id="menueDesignerTitle">Designed and developed by Retro-Code (Mr. Shahrokni)</h4>

    <p id="menueDescription" onclick="MyFunction()">
        ...
    </p>

</div>
```

*** The main Html***

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Monsters' Den</title>
    <link href="styles/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/Index.js"></script>
</head>
    <body id="mainBody" onload="initIndexPage()">

        <div id="mainContainer">

            <div id="centeredFrame">

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***How I load the embedded html into the div***

```
function getHtml(url) {

    var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // add a random param at the end of the url to avoid cached data. 
    url = url + "?p=" + Math.random;

    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlHttpRequest.send(null);

    var response = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
    return response;

}

function loadMenueinFrame() {

    var html = getHtml("./htmls/menue.html");
    var centeredFrame = document.getElementById("centeredFrame");
    centeredFrame.innerHTML = html;
}
```

I expect to see the consequence of the onclick event, but as it is described above it does not work. 
Hope you guys give me a hint. Thank you.

Comment: It should definitely work as long as MyFunction is in scope. You must have some other problem. But you should not have duplicate <head> tags. You can have a <script> tag outside of a <head> tag.

Comment: Js script files cannot load unless they are load from start. You cannot just append a script tag and get all the javascript content of that file

Comment: @weegee Perfect! it works fine. I am surprised because I actually tried your solution, but it didn't work. but now it works fine. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Load the script in your head tag 
`Let mySelectedElement = document.getElementByID("mainContainer");
mySelectedElement.addEventListener("click",  function getHtml(){
    //your handler here
})`

This should work I believe